# How to stop some functions on a website depending on "login" state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

On my website, I have coded "sign in" and "ask questions" using the devise gem ("for sign in") and scaffold (for "ask questions").

But in this case, anyone can create or edit or delete questions.

So if I want to set it so that only one user can create or edit and delete his questions, but anyone can see any questions (anyone can use "show" and "index method," but you need to sign in to use "create", "update" and "delete" method in Rails), how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your questions controller :

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, create, :update, :delete]
```

This `before_action` is called a filter, it makes sure the user is authenticated before executing any of the above actions.

To make only the user who made the question able to edit it and update it, you should do the following

in your view, show the edit link only if the current_user is the user who made the question :

```
<% if  question.user == current_user%>
        <%= link_to "Delete", question_path(question), method: :DELETE, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%=end%>
```

Assuming your model name is question.

And you need to secure the delete action in your controller as well,

```
def destroy
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])
        if current_user == @question.user
            @question.destroy
        end
    end
```

Comment: but after login,i can update and delete any questions by anyone.User can update and delete only his questions,so i thinh we will need more code to do that

Answer (score 0):

In your config/routes.rb you can set up the routes so that users can only access certain pages, as follows. NB. That where you write 'resources :questions' this will apply to ALL questions; where you write 'resource :question' this will pertain to only the question asked by that user.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :questions, only: [:index, :show]

  authenticated :user do
    scope module: :user do
      resource :question, except: :index, as: 'my_question'
    end
  end

end
```